# Coordinates of Fourth Vertex of Parallelogram

Tags: geometry, vectors, intuition

I have the points: $A=(1,2,0)$, $B=(-2,0,3)$, $C=(3,-4,-1)$, and I want to find the coordinate of a fourth point $D$ such that $ABCD$ is a parallelogram.

In the previous part of the question I worked out the angle between $ABC$ using the vector dot product.

I am quite confused because how I do know which sides of my parallelogram are parallel to each other? Is the solution unique? How do I know this? I can't picture the geometry. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are three possible parallelograms that include three given non-colinear points as vertices, with the additional point found by various combinations of:

$$\mathbf P_1+\mathbf P_2-\mathbf P_3$$

This can be justified in various ways - one way is to look at the need to have the midpoints of the diagonal coincide, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2153097/206402).

If you know which two points are not connected on the perimeter of the parallelogram, you would use those as $\mathbf P_1$ and $\mathbf P_2$ in the above formula. In this case assuming $A$ and $C$ are separated, we could calculate:

$$\begin{align}
D&=A+C-B \\
&= (1,2,0) + (3,-4,-1) -  (-2,0,3) \\
&= (6,-2,-4)
\end{align}$$

The three parallelograms correspond to adding the different coloured triangles to the original black triangle in this diagram:

[image]

Comment: What information would need to be given such that the point D is unique?

Comment: If you knew which two points are not connected on the perimeter of the parallelogram, you would use those as $\mathbf P_1$ and $\mathbf P_2$

Comment: you've been very helpful, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Hint -

Find mid point of AC and then using this mid point and point B find point D. As in parallelogram mid point of AC and BD is same.

Comment: Is this solution unique? If yes, why? If no, why not?

Answer (score 0):

we have $$\vec{BA}=[3,2,-3]$$, the searched point $D$ has the coordinates $(x,y,z)$ thus $$\vec {CD}=[x-3,y+4,z+1]$$ since $ABCD$ is a parallelogram we get $$x-3=3$$, $$y+4=2$$ and $$z+1=-3$$

Comment: Could I argue AB = (..., ..., ...), DC = (..., ..., ...) and equate in that sense? What limits me, if anything, in the direction vectors I use? That is my main issue...

Comment: yes you can also use $$AB=DC$$ both are the same vectors